# Getting 206 Partial Content and not sure why

Tags: apache, http-headers

I'm getting a 206 on some images, and I'm not quite sure why (thus how to solve it).

Basically all the images are being called through the css file.

```
background-image: url(Images/i-Background.jpg); //works
background-image: url(Images/i-NavHeader-Blank.png); //doesn't work
```

However firebug is showing two different sets of request headers for the request, but be damned if I can figure out what could be causing that. I know that the 206 is due to the Range being set, and for some reason on the non-working ones it is set to Range bytes=0-
where as the working ones have no Range header.

Is there any reason why some have different request headers to others?

Thanks,
Psy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, worked it out, was to do with filezilla deciding the pngs needed to be uploaded as ASCII rather than binary, and the server doesn't like ASCII pngs :p